# Cyanoacrylate glue and citric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I got some cyanoacrylate glue on my fingers yesterday which dried up quickly and would not fall. My daughter (n.b. she's 7th grade, no chemistry education but wants to be a chemist and reads a lot by herself) suggested I try citric acid. Her reasoning was that it's a harmless acid and "might dissolve the triple bond", or maybe hydrogen bonds will form between the "many hydroxides, which will make the glue more soluble".

So, after literally sticking my finger in a lemon for 15 min. half of the white substance was gone and the rest just gradually fell off in the next 1-2 hours.

My question is, what really happened? What was the reaction?

My meager organic chemistry knowledge from highschool is very inadequate for answering this.

Comment: Not sure exactly why the acid helped. But it is usually advised to immerse the glued body parts to water as warm/hot as one can withstand for minutes. The help is often said to be due sweating of glued skin.